# using sysdate in table causing error in not a valid month

Tags: sql, oracle

so I was doing my homework and the table is

```
Create TABLE Book
(
bookID number(2,0) not null, 
title char(50) not null,
catID char(2),
copyrightYear number(2,0),
isbnNumber char(50),
publisherID char(2),
purchasePrice number(4,2),
coverType char(10),
datePurchased date default sysdate,
pages number(4,0)
)
```

and when I insert the date inside it becomes an error ( not a valid month)

```
Insert into Book 
values (1, 'Dirk Luchte', 'PS', 93, null,'NE', 23.50,'Hard', '23-nov-1993',1012);
```

and when I try to use to_date statement

```
Insert into Book 
values (1, 'Dirk Luchte', 'PS', 93, null,'NE', 23.50,'Hard', to_date('23-nov-1993','DD-MM-YYYY'),1012);
```

the whole oracle crashed to blank, what can I do?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: MySQL does not even have a `to_date()` function. What name can you read in the title bar of your database manager?

Comment: Is the date coming from somewhere else and therefore has to be in that format?

Comment: I've justed edited MySQL out of the question. There're just too many Oracle-only bits.

Comment: OK - if you want to give the date in the format '23-nov-1993' then the model is 'dd-mon-yyyy' (notice "mon" in the middle, that indicates month in character format). Better, though, to give it as '23-11-1993' and use your current model, 'dd-mm-yyyy' (then you don't depend on silly things like NLS language). Then: You have `sysdate` in your title; how is that related to your question? I don't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm) for your homework, it isn't considered cheating (not at least more than asking in Stack Overflow):

> ### Format Models
>
> ```
> Element   Specify in TO_* datetime functions?     Description
> MM        Yes                                     Month (01-12; January = 01)
> ```

So `nov` is clearly not a number between 1 and 12, thus the error.

And please learn to not disregard the error messages (you didn't even think about sharing it here): they're here to help.

---

As about the *using sysdate in table causing error* title, you're confused. The default value of your column is not used: you assign a explicit value. If you want the default value, you have to leave the column out. That also means that you have to provide a column list in your query (which is anyway a good practice because your app will not break when you add new columns).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to specify a date literal is using the ISO format:

```
DATE '1993-12-23'
```